# mitsubishi l200 power window issue

Tags: power-windows, mitsubishi, dtc

I´ll need some help with identifying some DTC´s, right front passenger power window got stuck, so I have made some diag checks, I have found this trouble code list but I am lost:

U1507
LIN communication

U1508*4
Power window (DR) time-out
U1509*4
Power window (AS) time-out
U1510*4
Power window (RL) time-out
U1511*4
Power window (RR) time-out

U1534*4
Power window (DR) checksum error
U1535*4
Power window (AS) checksum error
U1536*4
Power window (RL) checksum error
U1537*4
Power window (RR) checksum error

These codes appeared, my question is, when DR stands for driver, RL for rear left, RR for rear right, does AS stands for Passenger? Thanks

Boris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out by searching for trouble codes that DR could be related to Data Register, but somehow I can´t figure out how this can be related to power windows and this still didn´t solved my question, is here someone skilled enough to help me? Thanks

Comment: I have finally found an answer in [this document on page 13](http://sult.us/pathfinder/PWC.pdf).